# setCurrentWidget applied after the end of a clicked signal

Tags: qt, click, qstackedwidget

When I create slots by name with this kind of syntax:

```
on_<widgetname>_clicked();
```

If I want to display a particular widget Inside this function it won't display until it reaches the end of the function.

That is, when I create the following function:

```
void MyWindow::on_myWidget_clicked()
{
    // the stackedWidget is composed of:
    // page_1 with myWidget
    // page_2 

    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->page_2);
    waitSomeTime();
}
```

whith

```
void MyWindow::waitSomeTime()
{
    QThread t;
    t.sleep(2); // Wait 2 seconds to see which line is going to be executed first.
}
```

When the code is launched, the 2 seconds elapsed first and only then the page_2 is displayed.

Why the line

```
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->page_2);
```

is not executed first?

Comment: The events are processed once the execution returns to the main event loop. Try adding `QApplication::processEvents();` between `ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->page_2);` and `waitSomeTime();`.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Also the answer below is very interesting since I used the QThread class in my program.

Answer (score 1):

> [void QThread::sleep(unsigned long secs)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#sleep) [static]
>   Forces the current thread to sleep for secs seconds.

the `waitSomeTime` function make the main (current) thread sleep, so it will block everything, even GUI processing. As @scopchanov commented, you could use [QApplication::processEvents()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents), which will process the event of `setCurrentWidget`. However, the whole GUI will still be blocked until the `sleep` is done, which means, that the widget will be shown, but won't be able to handle any operation.

So it would be better to use [QTimer::singleShot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) if you want to delay the work, or start another new `QThread` to do it.